# Python floating point determinism

Tags: python, floating-point, deterministic, non-deterministic

The code below (to compute cosine similarity), when run repeatedly on my computer, will output 1.0, 0.9999999999999998, or 1.0000000000000002.  When I take out the normalize function, it will only return 1.0.  I thought floating point operations were supposed to be deterministic.  What would be causing this in my program if the same operations are being applied on the same data on the same computer each time?  Is it maybe something to do with where on the stack the normalize function is being called?  How can I prevent this?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import math

def normalize(vector):
    sum = 0
    for key in vector.keys():
        sum += vector[key]**2
    sum = math.sqrt(sum)
    for key in vector.keys():
        vector[key] = vector[key]/sum
    return vector

dict1 = normalize({"a":3, "b":4, "c":42})
dict2 = dict1

n_grams = list(list(dict1.keys()) + list(dict2.keys()))
numerator = 0
denom1 = 0
denom2 = 0

for n_gram in n_grams:
    numerator += dict1[n_gram] * dict2[n_gram]
    denom1 += dict1[n_gram]**2
    denom2 += dict2[n_gram]**2

print(numerator/(math.sqrt(denom1)*math.sqrt(denom2)))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Floating-point math may be deterministic, but the ordering of dictionary keys is not.

When you call `.keys()`, the order of the resulting list is potentially random.

Thus the order of your math operations inside the loops are also potentially random, and thus the result is not going to be deterministic because while any *single* floating-point operation might be deterministic, the result of a series of operations is very much dependent on ordering.

You could enforce a consistent order by sorting your key lists.

Comment: Order of the dictionary is non-deterministic in Python 3.x only, unless explicitly configured in Python 2.x

Comment: So, would you recommend enforcing order, or just leaving it be in the category of "floating points aren't exact, oh well?"  All I'm going to be doing is eyeballing this data.  Would you change your answer if this data was going to be used in computations further down the line?

Comment: I'd typically just leave it in the "floating points aren't exact" realm.